# Is it possible to use inheritance on the `schema_extra` config setting of a Pydantic model?

Tags: python, inheritance, pydantic

For example I have the following toy example of a `Parent` Model:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra


class Parent(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.ignore
        validate_assignment = True
        schema_extra = {
            "version": "00.00.00",
            "info": "Parent description",
            "name": "Parent Name",
        }
```

The goal here is that all child models inherit the same schema and maybe add additional stuff to that schema.

```py
class Child(Parent):
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.ignore
        validate_assignment = True

        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(
            schema: dict[str, object], model: type["Child"]
        ) -> None:
            schema['info'] = 'Child Description'
            schema['name'] = 'Child Name'
            schema['additional stuff'] = 'Something else'
```

The code above does not work, since the `Config` in the child class completely overwrites the inherited `Config` from the parent, therefore in the child's schema we are missing the `version` for example.

As mentioned, I want for all inherited classes to have the same basic schema layout with some meta information and possibly change values or add to it. Is this even possible?

**Edit**
The solution from @Daniil-Fajnberg works well with one caveat. Having for example:

```
class Child(Parent):
    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema: dict[str, object]) -> None:
            schema["info"] = "Child Description"
            schema["additional stuff"] = "Something else"
            schema["name"] = f"{schema.get('title')}v{schema.get('version')}"
```

the resulting entry for `name` in the schema will be for example:

> 'name': "Nonev00.00.00"

FYI: In my setup I use `schema_extra` as static method on the parent as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Correction

First of all, this statement is not entirely correct:

> the `Config` in the child class completely overwrites the inherited `Config` from the parent

The `Config` itself [**is inherited**](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/model_config/#change-behaviour-globally). But individual `Config` attributes **are overridden**.

Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra


class Parent(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.allow
        validate_assignment = True


class Child(Parent):
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid


print(Child.__config__.extra)                # Extra.forbid
print(Child.__config__.validate_assignment)  # True
```

That being said, the problem you are facing is that you **are overriding** the `schema_extra` attribute in your `Child.Config`. In other words `Child.Config.schema_extra` **does replace** `Parent.Config.schema_extra`.

If we wish to make this specific attribute of the configuration **extensible** by child models rather than have them override it, we have to get a bit creative.

---

### Update for Pydantic 2.x

With newer Pydantic versions this has become quite easier. In the baseclass instead of setting schema extra, one can simply use [`__get_pydantic_json_schema__`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/json_schema/#implementing-__get_pydantic_json_schema__) to get the current schema and modify it.

##### Example Usage:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, GetJsonSchemaHandler, Field
from pydantic.json_schema import JsonSchemaValue
from pydantic_core import core_schema

def schema_extra(schema: dict[str, Any], model: type["Parent"]) -> None:
    schema["version"] = "1"
    schema["info"] = "Parent description"
    
class Parent(BaseModel, json_schema_extra=schema_extra):
    some_parent_property: str 

class Child(Parent):
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(
        cls, core_schema: core_schema.CoreSchema, handler: GetJsonSchemaHandler
    ) -> JsonSchemaValue:
        json_schema = handler(core_schema)
        json_schema = handler.resolve_ref_schema(json_schema)
        json_schema ["info"] = "Child Description"
        json_schema ["additional stuff"] = "Something else"
    return json_schema


print(Child.schema_json(indent=4))
```

### Updated Solution

I propose defining a custom `BaseModel` to use throughout the application, hooking into its [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) method and applying a custom function to "inherit" the `schema_extra` config attribute from all ancestor models (in reverse [MRO](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order)) iteratively.

To ensure that any `schema_extra` *function* calls are deferred until the schema dictionary is actually constructed, we will need to ensure that every subclass will have its `schema_extra` config value **as defined by the user** saved in a separate config attribute. This is different from my initial solution (see below), which was sub-optimal because it called the functions immediately during class creation and thus would not have access to some schema attributes/keys that are only created later.

This seems to work:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from functools import partial
from inspect import signature
from typing import Any, ClassVar, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBaseModel
from pydantic.config import BaseConfig as PydanticBaseConfig, SchemaExtraCallable


class BaseConfig(PydanticBaseConfig):
    own_schema_extra: Union[dict[str, Any], SchemaExtraCallable] = {}


class BaseModel(PydanticBaseModel):
    __config__: ClassVar[type[BaseConfig]] = BaseConfig

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: object) -> None:
        cls.__config__.own_schema_extra = cls.__config__.schema_extra
        cls.__config__.schema_extra = partial(
            inherited_schema_extra,
            base_classes=(
                base for base in reversed(cls.__mro__)
                if issubclass(base, BaseModel)
            ),
        )


def inherited_schema_extra(
    schema: dict[str, Any],
    model: type[BaseModel],
    *,
    base_classes: Iterable[type[BaseModel]],
) -> None:
    for base in base_classes:
        base_schema_extra = base.__config__.own_schema_extra
        if callable(base_schema_extra):
            if len(signature(base_schema_extra).parameters) == 1:
                base_schema_extra(schema)
            else:
                base_schema_extra(schema, model)
        else:
            schema.update(base_schema_extra)
```

Note that all this business with the `BaseConfig` annotation is mostly just to improve type safety and define our new `own_schema_extra` config attribute properly before using it. It is not strictly necessary to do this, but it makes this a cleaner solution.

##### Usage:

```py
class Parent1(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "version": "1",
            "info": "Parent1 description",
        }


class Parent2(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "version": "2",
            "info": "Parent2 description",
        }


class Child(Parent2, Parent1):
    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
            schema["info"] = "Child Description"
            schema["additional stuff"] = "Something else"
            schema["title+version"] = f'{schema["title"]}v{schema["version"]}'


print(Child.schema_json(indent=4))
```

##### Output:

```json
{
    "title": "Child",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {},
    "version": "2",
    "info": "Child Description",
    "additional stuff": "Something else",
    "title+version": "Childv2"
}
```

As you can see here, multiple inheritance for the schema is supported properly (because we follow the MRO to construct it) and the deferred call to the `schema_extra` functions allowed us to access the `title` key of the schema in one of them to construct the `title+version` value.

---

### Initial Solution (see OP/comments for caveat)

I propose hooking into [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) and applying a custom function to "inherit" the `schema_extra` config attribute from all parent models (in reverse [MRO](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order)) iteratively:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from inspect import signature

from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBaseModel


def inherit_model_schema_extra(model: type[BaseModel]) -> None:
    schema_extra: dict[str, object] = {}
    for parent in reversed(model.__mro__):
        if not issubclass(parent, BaseModel):
            continue
        parent_schema_extra = parent.__config__.schema_extra
        if callable(parent_schema_extra):
            if len(signature(parent_schema_extra).parameters) == 1:
                parent_schema_extra(schema_extra)
            else:
                parent_schema_extra(schema_extra, model)
        else:
            schema_extra.update(parent_schema_extra)
    model.__config__.schema_extra = schema_extra


class BaseModel(PydanticBaseModel):
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: object) -> None:
        inherit_model_schema_extra(cls)
```

The way `schema_extra` is handled here (i.e. as a callable or as a dictionary) is essentially copied from how the [`model_process_schema`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.9/pydantic/schema.py#L552) function in the current stable version does it. (see [line 591](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.9/pydantic/schema.py#L591) and following)

##### Usage:

```py
class Parent(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "version": "00.00.00",
            "info": "Parent description",
        }


class Child(Parent):
    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema: dict[str, object]) -> None:
            schema["info"] = "Child Description"
            schema["additional stuff"] = "Something else"


print(Child.schema_json(indent=4))
```

##### Output:

```json
{
    "title": "Child",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {},
    "version": "00.00.00",
    "info": "Child Description",
    "additional stuff": "Something else"
}
```

As you can see, the `Child` schema has both the `Parent` extras as well as its own, whereby its own extras take precedence.

Comment: Thanks, will test asap. Tbh, I was a bit worried, this would be a X/Y problem and my general design idea is flawed.

Comment: No, I actually think you raise very good point. I think this functionality of inheriting and updating `schema_extra` is a very sane approach to this setting and I wonder why it is not handled this way by default. If I have the time, I'll look into that and the Pydantic issue tracker later.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while, in my setup I am still missing the "base schema", meaning stuff like "title". I have to investigate the reason, might be my particular setup which has multiple inheritance and some ABC classes as well....

Comment: OK, I think I got it to work. However, we should probably add to the answer, that `schema_extra` gets now initially called at startup. At that time the default stuff (title, properties...) does not yet exits, so if one wants to use or change those must be careful. E.g. I have an entry which combines "title" and version, which ended up being `Nonev00.00.00` since title does not exist and afterwards the schema gets cached as far as I understand.

Comment: @RolandDeschain I think have an idea what you mean, but I am not sure. Do you mind editing your question so that your minimal example encompasses this special case as well? Please also add the desired output explicitly to make it easier to test the solution. Then I'll take another look at it.

Comment: I have added the issue to the OP

Comment: @RolandDeschain I updated the answer. I hope this works as intended now.

Comment: I will test it. In the meanwhile I have also tested around and added an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Going from the solution @Daniil-Fajnberg with the mentioned caveat, I have thrown together a quick and dirty solution using `functools`. Keep in mind, this is only a testing example which is not as sophisticated as the accepted answer - additionally it assumes all instances of `schema_extra` to be callable:

```
from functools import partial

def compose_func(f1, f2, schema, model):
    f1(schema, model)
    f2(schema, model)


def inherit_model_schema_extra(model: type[BaseModel]) -> None:#
    for parent in reversed(model.__mro__):
        if not issubclass(parent, BaseModel):
            continue
        parent_schema_extra = parent.__config__.schema_extra
        if callable(parent_schema_extra):
            model.__config__.schema_extra = partial(compose_func, parent_schema_extra, model.__config__.schema_extra)


class BaseParameterSet(BaseModel):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs: object) -> None:
        inherit_model_schema_extra(cls)

    class Config:
        extra = Extra.ignore
        validate_assignment = True
        
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(
            schema: dict[str, Any], model: type["BaseParameterSet"]
        ) -> None:
            schema["version"] = "00.00.00"
            schema["info"] = "Parameter set description"
            schema["name"] = "Parameter set Name"


class Child(BaseParameterSet):
    class Config:

        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(
            schema: dict[str, Any], model: type["BaseParameterSet"]
        ) -> None:
            schema["info"] = "Child Description"
            schema["additional stuff"] = "Something else"
            schema["name"] = f"{schema.get('title')}v{schema.get('version')}"
```

I have only tested with this a short while, so please take it with a grain of salt, but I would be interested in general opinions on this approach.

Comment: Hah, you also ended up using `functools.partial`. :) But I am not sure about this solution for two reasons: 1) It ignores the possibility of `dict`-like `schema_extra` (as you mentioned), but more importantly 2) you may run into trouble as soon as you add more inheritance levels because you just keep overwriting `schema_extra`. Essentially you would keep on recursively calling those functions, the deeper inheritance gets. That is why I used an additional config attribute to save the user-defined `schema_extra`. But I have not tested this solution yet, so maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Yes exactly, saw you use it too just now. Not the first time functools came for the rescue :D